# SVG <g> tag get its <title> content JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I have a g-tag part of a svg-tag, and I need its title content i.e. "Layer 2" in the case. 
Any easy way, **no regex**, just jquery or js ?

```
  <g style="pointer-events:none" display="none">
    <title style="pointer-events:inherit">Layer 2</title>
    <image x="20" y="20"></image>
  </g>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var title = $('g').find('title').text();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wfEk9/

Answer (score 1):

```
var title = $('g').find('title').html();
```

Demo : http://jsbin.com/OvEvEtUC/1/edit